# Convert non-nested json to nested json suitable for tree

Tags: python, json

For example，I have a json

```
[{name:func1,children:func},{name:func2,children:func},{name:main,children:[func1,func2,fun3]}
```

if I use this json to draw picture, I will got a picture like this
[not a tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROrcZ.png)

Now I want to draw a complete picture like this
[a complete tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89nFl.png)

so I have to change the previous json to

```
{name:main,children:[{name:func1,children:func},{name:func2,children:func},{name:func,children:null}]}
```

I want to know what actions should I do(use python or javascript) in a multi-level nested structure

Thanks！！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this is what you're looking for?

```
abc = [{"name":"func1","children":"func"},{"name":"func2","children":"func"},{"name":"main","children":"[func1,func2,func]"}]
list_at_end = list(abc[-1]['children'][1:-1])
list_at_end = ''.join(list_at_end).split(',')
needed_dict = []
for i in range(len(list_at_end)):
    if abc[i]['name']== list_at_end[i]:
        needed_dict.append(dict(abc[i]))
    else:
        needed_dict.append({'name':list_at_end[i], 'children': None})
abc[-1]['children'] = needed_dict 
abc[-1]
```

output

[image]